# Is it possible to set ofFloat to multiple targets?

Tags: java, android

I have this fade in function

```
    private void fadeIn() {
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ButtonA, "alpha", 0f, 1f);

        objectAnimator.setDuration(2000L);
        objectAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        });
        objectAnimator.start();
}
```

and right now the only target is ButtonA, i have 3 more buttons (ButtonB, ButtonC ....) is there anyway i can target all four without writing this codesnippet 4 times over?

Comment: pass button as function argument ```private void fadeIn(Object button) {```

Comment: @Zoe thx got it !

Comment: @Adi Will probably need a little better explanation to make it work sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private static void fadeIn(long duration, final View... views) {
    if (views == null) return;
    final ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    va.setDuration(duration);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            final float alpha = (float) animator.getAnimatedValue();
            for (View view : views) view.setAlpha(alpha);
        }
    });
    va.start();
}
```

how to use:

```
// first argument duration and then pass any number of views
fadeIn(2000, buttonA, buttonB, buttonC);
```